# JavaScript not firing method in the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying for the following code to fire an Action method in the controller.

```
<script>
    function updateSalary() {
        var salary = $('#basicSalary').val();
        var figure = $('#allowance').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("updateSalary","salary")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { salary: basicsalary, figure: allowance },
            success: function (add) {
                $('#basicSalary').val(salary)
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

**Razor:**

```
<td>
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.allowance, Model.allowances, "--please choose an option--", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "updateSalary()" })
</td>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult updateSalary (int salary, string figure)
        {
            if (figure == "Transport")
            {
                try
                {
                    allowance trans = hc.allowances.First(x => x.name == figure);
                    if (trans != null)
                        salary = +Convert.ToInt32(trans.amount);
                    else
                    throw new excep("Record not found");
                }
                catch
                {

                }                    
            }
            return Json(salary,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Basically `allowance` should get added to `basicSalary` field on the webpage when user selects the `allowance` dropdownlist. I've put a breakpoint on starting braces of `updateSalary` Action method to check if javaScript is firing it in the controller or not when I change the selection in `allowance` dropdownList. It is not firing. I can't figure out why. Could someone see why?

Comment: Is javascript function totaly not working? Or just ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some typos here:

```
data: { salary: basicsalary, figure: allowance }
```

should probably be:

```
data: { salary: salary, figure: figure }
```

given the names of the variables you declared at the beginning of your `updateSalary` javascript function.

In order to track this kind of problems I would recommending you using the developer toolbar of your browser. For example if you are using Google Chrome you could click <kbd>F12</kbd> to activate it and then in the `Console` tab look for javascript errors. Also when dealing with AJAX queries like you do, you could look at the `Network` tab which will show you all requests sent to the server as well as the corresponding response. This could give you a good indication where the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks for your guidelines. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong variable **basicsalary**  and **allowance** that is not defined. Change variable name from `salary` to `basicsalary` and `figure` to `allowance`

try this

```
var basicsalary = $('#basicSalary').val();
var allowance = $('#allowance').val();
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("updateSalary","salary")',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { salary: basicsalary, figure: allowance },
        success: function (add) {
            $('#basicSalary').val(add);
        }
  });
```

Comment: All is working as expected @Shamim. Now problem is with `success: function (add) {
            $('#basicSalary').val(salary)` line of code. In these two lines, I'm trying to get `salary` from the actionMethod and adding it to `basicSalary` field. `salary` is being returned as Jason. With the help of dubugger, I can see expected salary calculated correctly in line `return Json(salary,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` but is not somehow returning to the page and get added into the `basicSalary` field. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry I'm totally new to ajax and javaScript.

Comment: Please check my edit after getting success add this line `$('#basicSalary').val(add);`